# How to openfile in special program using autoit?

Tags: windows, autoit

I need to open a file in special program. For example, I need to open *.docx file if office word.

I have figured out how to run office

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad with the window maximized.
    Local $iPID = Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE", "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    WinWait("[CLASS:winword]", "", 5)

    ; Wait for 2 seconds.
    Sleep(2000)

    ; Close the Notepad process using the PID returned by Run.
    ProcessClose($iPID)
EndFunc   ;==>
```

How to open the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Word documents, just pass the name of the document as a command line argument

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad with the window maximized.
    Local $iPID = Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" & " " & "path_to_document", "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    WinWait("[CLASS:winword]", "", 5)

    ; Wait for 2 seconds.
    Sleep(2000)

    ; Close the Notepad process using the PID returned by Run.
    ProcessClose($iPID)
EndFunc   ;==>
```

Or use ShellExecute()